# Delete a single element from a nested list inside dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

- I want delete a single element inside a key `documents`, the list size can vary, so first I am counting the number of items inside list, and then I want to delete the `Object` element from `documents` list.
- I want to basically run the python for loop depending upon the list size, and delete the element from it. Not able to really figure out an approach for for loop.
- Input

```
    {
          "UserCode": "<user>",
          "ObjectType": "Document",
          "documents": [
            {
              "Object": "<base-64-string1>",
              "ObjectSourceFileName": "A1.json",
              "ContextKey": "A1.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
              "ObjectFormat": "csv"
            },
            {
              "Object": "<base-64-string2>",
              "ObjectSourceFileName": "A2.json",
              "ContextKey": "A2.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
              "ObjectFormat": "csv"
            },
            {
              "Object": "<base-64-string3>",
              "ObjectSourceFileName": "A3.json",
              "ContextKey": "A3.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
              "ObjectFormat": "csv"
            },
            {
              "Object": "<base-64-string4>",
              "ObjectSourceFileName": "A4.json",
              "ContextKey": "A4.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
              "ObjectFormat": "csv"
            }
          ],
          "ClientCode": "CL",
          "Source": "Client"
        }
```

- Expected Output

```
    {
          "UserCode": "<user>",
          "ObjectType": "Document",
          "documents": [
            {
              "ObjectSourceFileName": "A1.json",
              "ContextKey": "A1.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
              "ObjectFormat": "csv"
            },
            {
              "ObjectSourceFileName": "A2.json",
              "ContextKey": "A2.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
              "ObjectFormat": "csv"
            },
            {
              "ObjectSourceFileName": "A3.json",
              "ContextKey": "A3.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
              "ObjectFormat": "csv"
            },
            {
              "ObjectSourceFileName": "A4.json",
              "ContextKey": "A4.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
              "ObjectFormat": "csv"
            }
          ],
          "ClientCode": "CL",
          "Source": "Client"
        }
```

Comment: why do you need to count how long the list is if you either way want to delete `object` from every dictionary inside that list no matter how many there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `del` to remove the key from dictionary:

```py
dct = ... your dictionary from the question ...

for doc in dct["documents"]:
    del doc["Object"]

print(dct)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "UserCode": "<user>",
    "ObjectType": "Document",
    "documents": [
        {
            "ObjectSourceFileName": "A1.json",
            "ContextKey": "A1.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
            "ObjectFormat": "csv",
        },
        {
            "ObjectSourceFileName": "A2.json",
            "ContextKey": "A2.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
            "ObjectFormat": "csv",
        },
        {
            "ObjectSourceFileName": "A3.json",
            "ContextKey": "A3.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
            "ObjectFormat": "csv",
        },
        {
            "ObjectSourceFileName": "A4.json",
            "ContextKey": "A4.json2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
            "ObjectFormat": "csv",
        },
    ],
    "ClientCode": "CL",
    "Source": "Client",
}
```